# How to draw millimeter precise lines and boxes with React-pdf

Tags: reactjs, react-pdf

I tried the following code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Page,
  Document,
  StyleSheet,
  Svg,
  Line,
  Path,
  Rect,
  Text,
} from '@react-pdf/renderer';

// Create styles
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  page: {
    padding: 20,
  },
});

// Create Document Component
const MyDocument = () => (
    <Document>
      <Page size="A4" style={styles.page}>ä
        <Text>SVG Rect</Text>
        <Svg width={100} height={50}>
          <Rect x={0} y={0} width={100} height={50} strokeWidth={1} stroke={'#000'} />
        </Svg>
        <Text style={{marginTop: 20}}>SVG Path</Text>
        <Svg width={100} height={1}>
          <Path
              d="M 0 0 L 100 0"
              strokeWidth={1}
              stroke="black" />
        </Svg>
        <Text style={{marginTop: 20}}>SVG Line</Text>
        <Svg width={100} height={1}>
          <Line x1={0} x2={100} y1={0} y2={0} strokeWidth={1} stroke={'#000'} />
        </Svg>
      </Page>
    </Document>
);

export default MyDocument;
```

[Link to example in Live-Editor](https://react-pdf.org/repl?code=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)

This is the current result:

[image]

I printed it on an A4 paper.

**What happen**

`100` in the context of the code results in `350 mm` on the paper.

**What I like**

Have a 1 mm thick line with 100 mm width.

Is this even possible? I expect some math behind (maybe the DPI), but didn't figured it out yet.

Answer (score 0):

It seem, that SVG doesn't fit the needs. Maybe a workaround for this is to use `<View />` in combination with CSS millimeter unit.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Document, Page, View } from '@react-pdf/renderer';

const MyDocument = () => (
    <Document>
      <Page size="A4">
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
          <View style={{ width: '100mm', height: '100mm', border: '1mm solid black' }} />
        </View>
      </Page>
    </Document>
);

export default MyDocument;
```

[Live-Editor](https://react-pdf.org/repl?code=3187b0760ce02e004026260c0bc300500a06300f00451015c05b014cc2803e2db5c005010c0735260804b00bd4e4022010400b2f6ab4c6e006aed480773650027801b1e01bd54c00662a007802e18011800d0c064bd93300124a2962100c07260e4ec02727a6015a168ed34140185c0ec299d5c29493c60017d6345c4c470a565e594d43465d8e0a0002d9d0c00188b8988bc60f3492cf2a10a4aca2a008c41dce1a30acad8402ce0609a94198001ac9ce3626001e9129271275264677127185912e6098048dda8012801b8303000954886a0e8f000c400e9ddc9dbdcd011800e3080000)

[image]